MongoDB doesn't map POJO correctly in Java
I have mongodb database and POJO classes for them. Here's one of them:
import lombok.*;
import org.bson.codecs.pojo.annotations.BsonProperty;
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Builder
@Getter
public class Audience {
    @BsonProperty(value = "id")
    private ObjectId id;
    @BsonProperty(value = "aud_business")
    private double business;
    @BsonProperty(value = "media_info")
    private String mediaInfo;
    @BsonProperty(value = "aud_type")
    private String type;
    @BsonProperty(value = "places_amount")
    private int places;
}

I was testing getting Audience objects from "audience" collection, but the MongoCollection<Audience> returns me only empty objects (that are initialized with NoArgsConstructor), while Document works as it should.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder()
                .automatic(true)
                .build());
        CodecRegistry codecRegistry = fromRegistries(
                MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
                pojoCodecRegistry);
        MongoClientSettings clientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
                .codecRegistry(codecRegistry)
                .build();

        try (MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(clientSettings)) {
            MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("curriculum");
            MongoCollection<Document> audience1 = db.getCollection("audience", Document.class);
            MongoCollection<Audience> audience2 = db.getCollection("audience", Audience.class);
            Document audience3 = audience1.find(eq("media_info", "sdlkjf")).first();
            Audience audience4 = audience2.find(eq("media_info", "sdlkjf")).first();

            System.out.println(audience3);
            System.out.println(audience4);
         }

Document{{_id=67177a2b530cb42a1674eb7a, aud_business=50.0, id=67177a2b530cb42a1674eb79, media_info=sdlkjf, places_amount=12, aud_type=dslkjf}}
Audience(id=null, business=0.0, mediaInfo=null, type=null, places=0)

I've tried playing with BsonProperty, but nothing helped.

Should it be @BsonProperty(value = "_id") since that is the name of the field?

@Joe I've seen about that, you need to set @BsonProperty of id to "id" or just set @BsonId above it. In other case it will throw an error.
